# How to write "I saw this and thought of you" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm wanting to write "I saw this and though of you" in latin, and am struggling with the "of you" section (I'm only a beginner)... Should this be "de +abl" or is there another translation/idiom?

Hoc vidi et de te cogitavi?

Answer (score 6):

Your attempt is absolutely correct, *cogitare* is commonly used with *de* + ablative, meaning: "think of". It may be of interest to you that this verb can also be used with a plain accusative object, like: *te cogitabam*, "I was thinking of you".

But since you asked for alternative idioms: when you say "I thought of you" in this case, you are less saying "I was pondering you", but rather: "You came to mind." As it turns out, you can almost literally translate that to Latin:

> Mihi in mentem venisti.

*In mentem venire* is a common expression used lots by Cicero, for example.

Comment: Love the ciceronian expression, it perfectly corresponds to the Italian _venire in mente_ (e.g. _mi venisti in mente_)

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Some would say Latin never died, it's just called Italian today ;)

Answer (score 1):

I, at least, would understand your meaning. If I were writing it more emotionally, I would say:

(Hoc) donum spectavi, et fit velut pro oculis meis advenisti.

"I saw this gift, and it was as if you walked in front of my eyes."